# Execution plan not appearing for MyQL Workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have MySQL Workbench 8.0 and Mariadb Server 10.6.5. I want to check the performance of query with the help of Execution plan. However the tab is not working. I am getting the message "Explain data not available for statement". Explain Format = JSON is working but a visual plan will better.

Regards,
Saumik Vora

Comment: How did you run the `Explain`? What is the the query?

Comment: Oracle's MySQL Workbench doesn't offer all its features when connected to non-Oracle products like MariaDB.  "Workbench isn't done 'til MariaDB doesn't run."  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use the command line tool, `mysql`.

In it, do

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ... ;
```

or

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...;
```

Be aware that old versions of MySQL and MariaDB could Explain *only* `SELECTs`.

Personally, I don't find the "visual" plan adds anything.  And all flavors of Explain leave something to be desired.  Show us what you get; we can help you interpret it.  Note that one very important thing it fails to do is to suggest what index you *need to add*.

Text, not images, please.

Comment: I did in command line tool, both Explain and Explain JSON but everytime output comes as --> . I cannot do anything further without restarting the tool. Pls note OS is Windows.

Comment: On Windows, Start > Run -- That gives a small dialog box, in it type "cmd".  That will give you a new commandline window.  In _that_, type "mysql -u user -p database" or whatever gets you in.  (The details depend on whether you have a password and which database your table is in.)  Then you will see a prompt, probably "mysql >".  At _that_ point the "EXPLAINs" should work a stay on the screen long enough copy.

Comment: @Saumik - Remember that stuff -- you will need a "terminal" (aka "cmd") at other times in your life.

Comment: of course i did it in terminal only and the same way as you mentioned.